# How to write a logout function for my django app?

Tags: html, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

Here is `views.py`:

```
def authent(request):
    user = request.POST['username'] 
    passw = request.POST['password']
    featureDetail = []
    loginrole = People_Login.objects.get(User_Name = user, Password = passw)
    features = Role_FGroup_FSubGroup_FItems_Map.objects.filter(Role_Id = loginrole.id)
    for p in features:
        dic = {}
        dic['ID'] = p.id
        dic['Role_ID'] = p.Role_Id.id
        dic['FGID'] = p.Feature_Group_Id.id
        dic['FSGID'] = p.Feature_SubGroup_Id.id
        dic['FIID'] = p.Feature_Items_Id.id
        dic['SFGNAME'] = p.Feature_Group_Id.Name
        dic['SFSGNAME'] = p.Feature_SubGroup_Id.Name
        dic['SFINAME'] = p.Feature_Items_Id.Name
        featureDetail.append(dic)
    featuresgroups = Role_Feature_Group_Map.objects.filter(Role_Id = loginrole.Role_Id.id)
    request.session['feature_list'] = featureDetail
    request.session['featuresgroups'] = featuresgroups
    return render_to_response('UAM/index.html',{"contacts":featureDetail,'len':len(featureDetail)-1,'test1':"shiva",'test2':"shiva","featuresgroups":featuresgroups})
```

For this `authent` function how to write my logout function
(as I am new to Django)? Please go easy and give me the code for logout function.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Django's [built in authentication features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/) instead of rolling out your own. Otherwise, you're bound to make many mistakes (such as [storing plain text passwords](http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/), which I see it's what you're doing) and reinvent many wheels (such as session handling, groups and permissions, etc). If you need to store more information about users than Django supports, you can do it in the form or [user profiles](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile).

Anyway, if by "logged on" you mean "having those values in the session", to "log out" you just need to remove them, no?

Answer (score 1):

It really is this easy:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: The OP is **not** using `django.contrib.auth`, but a custom solution. However, having read the source code from `logout` I can see it will in fact do the job of clearing session data, without touching anything in the DB (which could cause an error, since the requered tables aren't present). So I guess this is a valid answer indeed...